# What's the different between WebID and IDL(XPIDL)?

Tags: ipc, idl, b2g, webidl

> WebIDL : Is the interface description language used to describe the
> data types, interfaces, methods, properties, and other components
> which make up a Web application programming interface (API).
>
> IDL(XPIDL) : It is an Interface Description Language used to specify
> XPCOM interface classes. (XPIDL is expected to converge towards WebIDL
> in the future.)

Those two interfaces using XPCOM to implement the cross-language IPC mechanism.

So, my questions are :

1. What's the different between WebIDL and XPIDL?
2. Why IDL will converge towards WebIDL in the feature?

Thank you.

Comment: WebIDL is an interface and using dom binding to do the language binding from GAIA to Gecko's content process.